# Convert decimal to hex string without 0x in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I want to convert

```
string
------
BB
C1
GB
```

to

```
hex
---
4242
4331
4742
```

using

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(2), 'B1')
```

Result is '**0x4231**'

but I want remove the `0x` from the result, so I tried `varbinary` to string:

```
SELECT CONVERT([VARCHAR](MAX), CONVERT(BINARY(2), 'B1', 2))
```

result is '**?**'

Then I tried

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(BINARY(2), 'B1'), 2, 4)
```

result is '**0x42**'

How to convert 'B1' to '4231'?

Comment: DO NOT confuse the actual binary value stored in a variable/column with the respresentation used to display it in a manner that you can SEE. The "0x" bit (in your first query) is an artifact of the manner in which SSMS displays that particular datatype.

Comment: Rarely is this something you need to do using tsql. So that begs the question of what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to hex using the system function `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr`, then remove the first two characters.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(binary(2), 'B1')),3,999)
```

Output:

```
4231
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself

```
SELECT convert(varchar(4), convert(binary(2), ('B1')), 2)
```